# Encrypt xml file in.net and Decrypt encrypted file in java using x509 certificate

Tags: java, .net, encryption, x509certificate2

I am new to xml encryption i want to encrypt xml file in .net and decrypt the encrypted file in java using x509 certificate. Can this be done?

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx) this may be usefull for you.

Comment: @PLB: i gone through link but i want encrypted file to be decrypted at java end..

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244548/digital-signature-with-x509-certificate-and-encryption) check this too. I am not good at java, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the example below

```
public class CryptoUtil {

public static byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] publicKey, byte[] data) throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey);

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(byteOutputStream, rsa);
    os.write(data);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return byteOutputStream.toByteArray();

}

public static byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] privateKey, byte[] data) throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
    ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    InputStream is = new CipherInputStream(byteInputStream, rsa);
    byte[] message = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    is.close();
    return message;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfectly possible. You can encrypt a file using any well known algorithm using some programming language and decrypt it with another programming language.
For encryption using x509 in c#, have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx

Comment: thanks for relpay. but i already used the same example from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx but i dont know how to decrypt encrypted file on java end